# Search and replace on variable name within S-Expression (lexical scope)?

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, s-expression, paredit

Using emacs with Paredit enabled.  How can I search through a LISP (Clojure) S-expression and rename a variable?  I'd like to do it within the current S-expression instead of globally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `C-M-<space>` at the start of the s-expression you'd like to use as your scope, to highlight it, and then do a `query-replace` as usual - it restricts itself to the active region.

Answer (score 2):

The `query-replace` with active region is quite good for general
search/replace in region.  But for refactoring code, I much prefer [iedit](https://github.com/victorhge/iedit).

To rename a variable within a defun, go to the symbol to be reanmed, press 
<kbd>C-0 C-;</kbd> and edit away.

To rename a variable within arbitrary region, go to the symbol, press
<kbd>C-;</kbd>, select the region of interest, and press <kbd>C-;</kbd> again.

iedit has many other functions to help code refactoring.  Hint: <kbd>C-'</kbd>